# when to use ConsumerWidget and consumer?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

So, I am fairly new to Riverpod and I use Riverpod mainly because of less page rebuild but when should I use ConsumerWidget as I saw when I use ConsumerWidget it rebuilds the whole widget tree but when using only consumer on that button that it only rebuilds the button's state not whole page.
so, when should I use ConsumerWidget and Consumer?

Comment: Both are acting similarly.  If something is watched in either a consumer widget or a consumer builder, then the adjacent things in that widget or builder are considered for rebuilding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of choice. You could use Consumer everywhere, or ConsumerWidget instead.

The recommendation is to generally use ConsumerWidget, for the fact that:

- They can have a const constructor, so enable more performance optimizations than Consumers.
- They promote splitting large components into smaller chunks

For example you could do:

```dart
class SomeOtherPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SomeOtherPage({required this.label, super.key});
  final String label;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref){
    return Column(
      children:[
      Text(label),
      const MyText();
    ],
   );
  }
}

class MyTest extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyTest({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref){
    final value = ref.watch(myProvider);
    return Text(value);
  }
}
```

In that scenario, if `SomeOtherPage.label` changes, `MyTest` will correctly not rebuild and instead only rebuild if `myProvider` changes.

Answer (score 5):

Usually `ConsumerWidget` is used for pages/UI components.
For example:

```
class SomePage extends ConsumerWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref){
     SomeValue value = ref.watch(someProvider);

     return SomeWidget(value);
}
```

On the other hand `Consumer` is used to watch the provider values locally.
For example:

```
class SomeOtherPage extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Column(
      children:[
      Text('Consumer'),
      Consumer(
         builder: (context, ref, child) {
          final value = ref.watch(someOtherProvider);
          return Text(value); 
        },
      ),
    ],
   );
  }
```

It's recommended to use `Consumer` when you need to update a little chunk of your widget tree where re-rendering the whole tree is costly.